# How to send FullDocument from Debezium Mongodb connector in Pulsar

Tags: debezium, apache-pulsar

guys. I've tried to do the poc about Apache Pulsar for my project. I tried to connect MongoDB to Pulsar function via the connector for detect any change events in the database. Everytime I updated data in my database, the field 'after' gonna be None like this:

```
key:[null], properties:[], content:[2023-04-26 08:48:48 +0700] [INFO]: Message: {'after': None, 'patch': '{"$v": 1,"$set": {"weight": 88866.0}}', 'filter': '{"_id": {"$numberLong": "99999"}}', 'source': {'version': '1.7.2.Final', 'connector': 'mongodb', 'name': 'dbserver1', 'ts_ms': 1682473726000, 'snapshot': 'false', 'db': 'inventory', 'sequence': None, 'rs': 'rs0', 'collection': 'products', 'ord': 1, 'h': -7862253894267628373, 'tord': None, 'stxnid': None}, 'op': 'u', 'ts_ms': 1682473727030, 'transaction': None}
```

How can I config this field to always has a value?

I tried to set `capture.mode` in the connector config following to [this document](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-connector-properties) but 'after' still be None.

Comment: Can you share source code?